# How to apply a buttonStyle in Android?

Tags: java, android

I have this Theme,

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="@style/AppBaseTheme">
    <item name="android:buttonStyle">@style/MyButtonStyle</item>
</style>
```

I need to define another style for a button (called MyButtonStyleDealer).

Using the following code I get error `android:buttonStyle` has been already defined.

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="@style/AppBaseTheme">
    <item name="android:buttonStyle">@style/MyButtonStyle</item>
    <item name="android:buttonStyle">@style/MyButtonStyleDealer</item>
</style>
```

I would like to know if it possible define a second style for the button and how to apply it to the View.

Comment: you can use the style attribute in the xml (I am not sure if I got correctly your question)

Comment: could you post an example please? My component it is based on Button but I cannot get the style property in the XML.

Comment: Two `AppTheme` into same file??

Comment: my problem is also that every button get styled with MyButtonStyle, I need have an exception and for a specific button apply another style.

Comment: @gibbok

1) http://www.mindfreakerstuff.com/2012/09/50-useful-android-custom-button-style-set-1/
2) http://androidcookbook.com/Recipe.seam;jsessionid=8BED36512503CA63614CA9237248CBE7?recipeId=3307
3) http://www.starkinfotech.com/android-custom-button/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If got your question correctly, you can add inside your style file another entry for the button

```
 <style name="MyNotClickableButtonStyle">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/my_button_background</item>
    <item name="android:clickable">false</item>
</style>
```

and inside your layout,

```
<Button 
     style="@style/MyNotClickableButtonStyle"
```

Answer (score 0):

You only can define one android:buttonStyle. If you want to change only this the button style has to add another style.

Another properties can be used if you want but only once.
For instance:

```
<style name="GlobalAppTheme" parent="Theme.Sherlock.Light">
        <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/ActionBar</item>
        <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/ActionBar</item>
        <item name="android:editTextStyle">@style/GlobalTextView</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/text_gray</item>
        <item name="android:checkboxStyle">@style/CheckBox</item>
        <item name="android:radioButtonStyle">@style/RadioButton</item>
        <item name="android:buttonStyle">@style/Button</item>
        <item name="android:textSize">14sp</item>
        <item name="android:actionBarItemBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
        <item name="actionBarItemBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
        <item name="android:alertDialogStyle">@style/Theme.Sherlock.Light.Dialog</item>
    </style>

<style name="GlobalAppTheme2" parent="Theme.Sherlock.Light">
            <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/ActionBar</item>
            <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/ActionBar</item>
            <item name="android:editTextStyle">@style/GlobalTextView</item>
            <item name="android:textColor">@color/text_gray</item>
            <item name="android:checkboxStyle">@style/CheckBox</item>
            <item name="android:radioButtonStyle">@style/RadioButton</item>
            <item name="android:buttonStyle">@style/Button</item>
            <item name="android:textSize">14sp</item>
            <item name="android:actionBarItemBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
            <item name="actionBarItemBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
            <item name="android:alertDialogStyle">@style/Theme.Sherlock.Light.Dialog</item>
        </style>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set sepecific styles like this:

```
<Button    
android:id="@+id/button_send"    
android:layout_width="wrap_content"    
android:layout_height="wrap_content"    
android:text="@string/button_send"    
android:onClick="sendMessage"    
style="?android:attr/MyButtonStyleDealer" />
```